# How to set ERRORLEVEL in SSIS?

Tags: ssis, batch-file, batch-processing, errorlevel

I have a batch file that runs an SSIS job. I have no knowledge of how the SSIS job runs, I took over a project involving it.

The batch file uses %ERRORLEVEL% to detect errors that occur within the SSIS job.  It must be expanded to report other errors too.

How do I set the ERRORLEVEL in SSIS?

Comment: Were you trying to set ERRORLEVEL (the final status of a program) or ERRORCHECK?

Comment: The batch file takes ERRORLEVEL and sets ERRORCHECK to that value, so I guess I have to set ERRORLEVEL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't appear to be possible. Based on the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162810.aspx), dtexec can only return error codes from 0-6.
If you need more detailed error trapping, you will need to store and parse the output from dtexec.